# I have a 13 mile commute, and I'm looking to buy a new bike

Tags: commuter

I'm currently riding a mountain bike from Wal-Mart, takes me about an hour. When I get my tax return, I plan buying a more appropriate bike for the commute. I'd like to stay around $300-400, and this would be the second bike I would buy, so I'd appreciate any suggestions and advice.

Comment: Voting to close: Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they tend to become obsolete quickly. Try your local bike shop and look at used hybrids.

Comment: Please read through the SE Bicycles tour here   http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/tour
We don't do product recommendations, however we can answer more general questions like "what features do I need or don't want on a commuter bike"   Do also use the search functionality first - there's already a trove of useful answers on the site.

Answer (score 0):

Used. You can find some decent used bikes in that range.  A hybrid might be a good choice.  You find people that paid $800 - $900 for bike they never used and it will sell used as low as $300.  Be patient and low ball.  Learn how to inspect a bike.  If you are on a budget you need to learn how to maintain a bike.

Comment: -1 Why would you answer this? This is clearly an inappropriate question if not a duplicate.

Comment: @BSOrider Then find a duplicate and mark it. This is a guy that rides 13 miles to work on a wally mart and is excited about spending a tax refund on an upgrade. Can you spell compassion?